# To apply a CSS style to every TD element of table

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I am trying to apply a style to a table with ID DataContainer like this:

```
     $("#DataContainer td").addClass("width200");
    $("#DataContainer th").addClass("width200");
```

however it applies class to TH elements in table head but not in the regular TDs under TBODY section.

Could you please suggest me a right selector for that?

Comment: can you share your table structure with us ?

Comment: AFAIK they should both work correctly. Getting any errors? Can you give us some HTML?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('#DataContainer').find('td').addClass("width200");
```

should select all td children of DataContainer. see [jQuery .find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) for more details