# How do I chain jquery selectors properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to implement a quick search/filter function to my table using jquery. In essence I want to hide all the rows that don't have the string I'm looking for from a searchbox to be hidden.

I have a dynamically created table and a text field used as the filter for the list.

Table:

```
<table id="report-table" class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="">client</th>
        <th class="">coach</th>
        <th class="">groups</th>

    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="name">John</td>
        <td class="coach">Peter </td>
        <td class="groups"> Skiers </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Ihave a function tied to the change event of the search text box. In this function I essentially want to **choose all tr that do not contain the text string in name or coach column and add a class to them.**  I have tried many things but have not gotten the syntax right, how should it be written?

```
hideSearch: function(e){

        console.log("hideSearch called");
        var searchValue = this.$el.find('.search-text').val();

        if(!searchValue ){
            console.log("hideSearch: empty search param");
            this.$el.find('tr').removeClass('hidden');
        }
        else{
            console.log("hideSearch: searched for: " + searchValue);
            //$('(#name, #groups):contains:not("'+searchValue+'")').parent().addClass('hidden');
            var selection =$('#name, #groups').('*:contains("'+searchValue+'")');

            console.log(selection);
            //console.log($('#name, #groups').('*:contains("'+searchValue+'")'));
            //$('(#name, #groups):contains("'+searchValue+'")').parent().addClass('hidden');
            //$('#name, #groups').('*:contains:not("'+searchValue+'")').parent().addClass('hidden');

        }
```

Comment: probably relevant for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15219790/to-apply-a-css-style-to-every-td-element-of-table/15219877#15219877

Comment: See this http://jsfiddle.net/pythondave/JUZDf/

Comment: hmm somebody wrote an asnwer to my syntax problem that worked with a small fix to add .parent(), but seems like he deleted his answer...

Comment: oh the id was a typo, fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#name, #groups').('*:contains("'+searchValue+'")');` would basically try to access the property `*:contains("foo")` (assuming `searchValue` is `"foo"`) of the object returned by `$('#name, #groups')`. I believe I don't have to say that jQuery objects don't have properties with such strange names.

First of all you have to give all the cells a common *class* instead of an ID. Then you should select all rows and see if either `.name` or `.coach` contain the search value. Use [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to get those for which neither cell matches:

```
$('#report-table > tbody > tr').filter(function() {
    return $(this).children('.name').text().indexOf(searchValue) === -1 &&
           $(this).children('.coach').text().indexOf(searchValue) === -1;
}).addClass('hidden');
```

The filter callback returns `true` if neither the `.name` cell nor the `.coach` cell contain the search value. Those rows for which the callback returns `true` are kept in the selection and are getting the class `hidden` added to them.

Comment: how is using the indexOf better compared to your previous answer of using .not(':contains("' + searchValue + '")') ?

Comment: My previous answer hat a major flaw: If in one row, `.name` contained the search term but `.coach` didn't, the row would still be hidden. That's because every cell was checked individually without taking into account that another cell in the same row could match. This has nothing to do with `:contains` or `.indexOf`, just how the elements have been processed. If you don't like `.indexOf` in the above solution, you could also use `$(this).children('.name:contains("' + searchValue + '")').length === 0` instead. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah, the thank you for clarification, that would have resulted in bug hunting in the evening!